# Code splitting in Vue SSR / Episerver solution

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering, episerver, dynamic-import

We have, because of various reasons, a rather special solution with an epi backend bundled with a Vue SSR frontend.
The frontend nodejs server only supplies the SSR and is not used as a webserver.
This means no frontend routing is used and the page is reloaded and setup for every page load.

As of now all components (for example a hundred epi blocks and pages) are registred globally since we dont know where and when they will be needed.
This of course creates a unnecessary large js bundle with like 90% of the code never used.

**My question is;
Until we rebuild the solution completely (for future headless epi support) is there a way to split the components and dynamically load only the ones needed for every page load?**

From what I've understand (and my testing) you cant use dynamic imported components with Vue SSR without using routing.

**For example I'd like every component to be a separate file so they could be cached and keep the initial page load smaller. Or if anyone has a better suggestion =)**

Answer (score 0):

We did something similiar with web pack bundling. We read the blocks within the content area, then bundled and loaded the blocks, using [webpack-import-glob-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-import-glob-loader) and [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Sorry for late answer. We do use webpack but I can't see how glob-loader and terser-webpack would help us achieve this. Maybe if you have some details?